# Alternative for "locate" on debian

Tags: debian, centos, locate

I often use "locate" command on CentOs to find files.

What's the alternative for this command on Debian ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I recommend [`locate`](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/locate).

```
sudo apt-get install locate
```

Comment: You may have to `sudo updatedb` to build an index.

Comment: In my case, `locate` did provide the command, but the package `mlocate` gave me some configuration files such as `/etc/updatedb.conf` that allowed for smoother use.

Answer (score 12):

**locate**
As the word itself suggests to *locate* files maybe you can install `locate` command, from the original [GNU findutils](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/findutils/) ([code here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/findutils/)), or from the new implementation [Debian buster](https://packages.debian.org/buster/locate) (on the right side the link to the sources).

**whereis**
To locate only *the binary, source, and manual page files for a command* you can always use `whereis`, remembering that *whereis has a hard-coded path, so it may not always find what you're looking for* (if not included in that hard-coded path).

> The whereis command is part of the util-linux package and is available
>   from  https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/

**which**
**which** instead locates a command and *returns the pathnames of the files (or links) **which would be executed** in the current environment, **by searching the $PATH** for executable files matching the names of the arguments.*
If used with `-a` option  it will print all matching pathnames of each argument.

**find**
Less efficient in terms of time, more slow because there isn't a database, it can result more efficient in terms of solutions proposed. 
Locate needs that the database is updated, (run `updatedb` frequently), if not you will have a partial or wrong result. Moreover, it is possible that some extensions or directories are excluded from the database (see `/etc/updatedb.conf` file).

**Desktop solutions**
If you are searching only for a program indexed with a *database*,  you can see projects for desktop such as  [Nepomuk](http://nepomuk.semanticdesktop.org/), [Strigi](http://www.vandenoever.info/software/strigi/), [Soprano KDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soprano_%28KDE%29), [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) and [Akonadi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akonadi), but even [Deskbar-applet](https://projects.gnome.org/deskbar-applet/), [Beegle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_%28software%29) for Gnome.
They are somehow similar to the discontinued Google Desktop.
Some of the database systems can be used from command line too.

Comment: If interested, it is possible to find some additional words [About Strigi, Soprano, Virtuoso et cetera](https://trueg.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/about-strigi-soprano-virtuoso-clucene-and-libstreamanalyzer/) and some of their differences, probably not completely on-topic here.

Answer (score 7):

You can have `locate` on Debian as well—you may just need to install it. There are (at least) two implementations available, in the locate and mlocate packages.

Installing either one will give you a `locate` command.

The mlocate version has some additional features (hiding names based on permissions, faster indexing).

Comment: [pagure.io/mlocate](https://pagure.io/mlocate) is the new official home site of mlocate.

Comment: @PabloBianchi *(confused)* I'm not sure what that has to do with this answer—any Debian user is going to `apt install mlocate` (or similar) to install it. Could you please elaborate how you're suggesting I improve the answer (or maybe just suggest an edit?). On the off-chance you're reporting the outdated location at https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/mlocate and in the package, that should be sent to Debian as a bug report. I've just done so, see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=867640

Comment: @deribert mlocate developer (Miloslav Trmac) just told me about [this recently change](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1468131#c1). I think is very useful for people to know official sites of projects in order to let them get involve. I would be happy to suggest an edit if you think so.

Answer (score 4):

Use `find`

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -name filename
```

Comment: thanx, unfortunately find doesn't use prebuilt database of files. Is there something like "locate" there that uses index ?

Comment: You can use `locate` by installing it on your debian distro as others suggested :)

Comment: If you are searching only for the ones with a _database_ please edit your question to have more proper answers. Find is a valid alternative to locate in the terms of your actual answer. It can offer you results that locate cannot.

Comment: also sometimes the database is old and locate can't find your file. So don't rely on locate.

Comment: *"So don't rely on locate."* That's mediocre advice unless you have reason to think that file might be recent or already know where to look. A full-filesystem `find` (which is the proper equivalent to `locate`) is an inefficient process that will slam the disk cache and may take a considerable time to complete.

Answer (score 1):

### [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)

I use it to look **inside** source code/files and this alias similar to [mlocate](https://pagure.io/mlocate) for filenames:

```
alias superlocate='bash -xc '\''ag -g $0 --hidden'\''  2>/dev/null'
```

#### Notes

- This and more probably could be accomplished with `ripgrep`.
- Also, now become popular `plocate`, which is faster, but lacks of `--transliterate` option, which [I found](https://askubuntu.com/q/908881/349837) extremely useful.
- A faster alternative to find could be [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)